# nvme list does not list UEFI installed NVMe drive

Tags: uefi, nvme

I have new SKHYNIX NVMe board.  "nvme list" listed board OK.  I installed Ubuntu on the board but had to use UEFI (:-P) to install  Ubuntu 21.04.  Now running "nvme list" shows zero NVMe drives.  The UEFI NVMe boots Ubuntu just fine, but I cannot detect that it is an NVMe.  I moved USB connected NVMe to another system and had the same problem.

How do I get past the UEFI to detect the NVMe drive?

Comment: NVMe is a connection technology like SATA & USB. If you are using an adapter to use a NVMe drive in a USB port, it then is a USB drive & speed is then limited to USB port speeds. Best to use USB-C as that is faster.

Comment: I'm using a ROG Stix Arian container, which is connected thru a USB-C cable.  Speed is not the issue, the issue is that I can no longer detect the drive card using the nvme-cli command: nvme list.